# Best way of creating different instance types(facotry method) with business logic?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

Say I am trying instantiate an instance of a `Table`. Table here denotes a `restaurant table` used for eating. Say I have 3 different table types

```
enum TableTypes {
    SMALL,
    MED,
    LARGE
}
```

I have some questions on the best way for the following

1. Should I have 3 separate lists that hold available instances of 3 table types?
2. Should I then based on (1) have 3 lists that hold these 3 table types when the tables are occuppied?
3. To grab a table, I need to put the business logic and move the table from free list to occupied list.

What is the best design pattern for this to use?

Comment: I think you have a good description of the use case, however questions asking for design patterns are not generally well-received. They are too open-ended for the Q&A format of this community. Is there a specific design problem you would like help with? If so, please [edit] your question to include more information about the problem you are trying to solve, and limit questions to one problem at a time.

Comment: And very likely there is no design pattern for this. Any edits to your question should include the necessary requirements your application needs to fulfill.

Comment: A factory is for creating things. Sounds like you don't want to actually create a table but retrieve one from a list. Perhaps you need to write a repository instead.

Comment: For me is sounds like the intent of the object pool pattern, but for a different reason: "reuse and share objects that are expensive to create".

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple implementation possible, either of factory pattern flavours - factory, static factory method, abstract factory - are suitable solutions.

Following is a shallow suggestion of implementation.

With the level of details from description Table instances could be supplied by an abstract factory design pattern implementation.

```
public enum TableType {

    SMALL {
        @Override
        public SmallTable newIt() {
            return new SmallTable();
        }
    }
    , MEDIUM {
        @Override
        public MediumTable newIt() {
            return new MediumTable();
        }
    }
    , LARGE {
        @Override
        public LargeTable newIt() {
            return new  LargeTable();
        }
    };
    
    public abstract Table newIt();
}

public class Table implements Serializable {}

public class SmallTable extends Table {}

public class MediumTable extends Table {}

public class LargeTable extends Table {}
```

While grabbing / ungrabbing tables could be modelled by a non-blocking first in first out (FIFO) implementation with two `java.util.Dequeue` instances that could be of type `java.util.LinkedList`, one for grated tables and one for free tables, calling `offer` method to add tables and `poll` method to remove tables.

```
public class TableGrabber<T extends Table> {

    private final Deque<T> grabbed;

    private final Deque<T> ungrabbed;

    public TableGrabber(Collection<T> tables) {

        this.grabbed = new LinkedList<T>();
        this.ungrabbed = new LinkedList<T>(tables);

    }

    public T grab() {
        T table = ungrabbed.poll();
        while (!grabbed.offer(table)) {}
        return table;
    }

    public T ungrab() {
        T table = grabbed.poll();
        while (!ungrabbed.offer(table)) {}
        return table;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Factory pattern is more suitable when you have to create instances of certain classes which are derived from a common base class(in this case Table). In your case the number of tables is already known so you can instantiate all the classes in the beginning, and keep them in an array, then use them when you need them. That does not prevent you to use a in implementation of a factory pattern, but you might also want to take a look on object pool pattern, maybe flyweight.

Later Edit: [Object Pool pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/object-pool-pattern) intent: reuse and share objects that are expensive to create.